# StringBuilder is working abnormally while using it in Recursion

Tags: java, queue, stringbuilder

I don't know either my implementation have bugs or `StringBuilder` is going wrong. From the stackoverflow, i got to know that `Java Strings` are immutable. Currently i am doing some string processing in a recursive fashion using `StringBuilder`. To make recursion more clear and understandable i am using a `Queue` to store `StringBuilder`. The same processing can be done with `String`s but it will increase the execution time, so i am using `StringBuilder`. The input string is first converted to `StringBuilder` then added to `Queue` after that a for loop matches it character and replaces substring with a `char`. This resultant `StringBUilder` is added to the `Queue`. Then an element(`StringBuilder`) is removed from the `Queue` and processed with  for loop in the same previous manner. This process is repeated until the `Queue` is not empty. Below is my code snippet-

```
    Queue<StringBuilder> q = new LinkedList<StringBuilder>();
    StringBuilder sb;
    q.add(new StringBuilder("abcccc"));
    while ((sb = q.poll()) != null) {
        int len = sb.length();

        for (int i = 0; i < len - 1; i++) {
            /*
             * Here i am matching charAt(i) with charAt(i+1) and based on
             * the characters matching decision is done
             */

            StringBuilder rep = new StringBuilder(len - 1);
            rep = sb;
            rep.replace(i, i + 2, replace);//replace is a string which is a character
            q.add(rep);
            }
    }
```

This gives me `StringIndexOutOfBoundsException`. However i am not changing the content of original `StringBuilder`, which is sb. I am just creating a copy of `sb` which is `rep`, then replacing the content of this newly created `StringBuilder`.

Comment: You're discarding that `new StringBuilder()` by immediately re-assigning `rep`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`rep = sb` is not creating a copy of `sb`.  Both of those objects are now pointing to the same StringBuilder instance.

Comment: `StringIndexOutOfBoundsException` will indirectly pointing that the size of `sb` is changed. Yeah.. you are right Mr. Mike. So what can be done now? How can i create a copy of `sb`? My alternate approach is to append the substrings of sb to rep. but that trick is not working for `string index=0`.

Comment: One way to copy would be to instantiate rep like this: `StringBuilder rep = new StringBuilder(sb.toString());`

Comment: This is cool but as far as `String`s are concerned, they are immutable and my recursion can be very large based on the input. So will this `sb.toString()` not increase the execution time?
 As an alternative what i am doing is-`StringBuilder rep = new StringBuilder(len - 1);`
`rep = sb;`
`rep.append(sb.substring(0, i));`
`rep.append(replace);`
`rep.append(sb.substring(i + 1));`
`q.add(rep);`

Comment: Alternately: `StringBuilder rep = new StringBuilder(sb)`.  It does have a `CharSequence` constructor, after all.

Comment: `StringBuilder rep = new StringBuilder(sb)` seems more faster than converting a `StringBuilder` to sting than that of creating a new `StringBuilder`.

Answer (score 2):

It looks to me like you are assigning the `sb` reference to `rep`, not creating a copy.

If you want a copy, use the StringBuilder constructor that accepts a string as the initial value:

```
StringBuilder rep = new StringBuilder(sb.toString());
```

http://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.5.0/docs/api/java/lang/StringBuilder.html

Comment: `String` are immutable, but if at all i have to convert `sb` to string, then a character replacement in a specified index `i`, then is there any other way? Because in the end i have to add a `StringBuilder` string in queue.

Comment: String's are immutable, but your new StringBuilder is a mutable object initialized with a copy of sb's string value following this approach.

Comment: I have one more question. I can create a copy of `StringBuilder` directly using `StringBuilder rep = new StringBuilder(sb)`. But in reality the length of my string is decreasing by 1 character every time but if i create `StringBuilder` using either `new StringBuilder(sb.toString());
 ` or `new StringBuilder(sb)`. this will unnecessary takes one memory, which is not required. (Since two characters are now  replaced with one character in string )
Can you propose any better way? also correct me if i am wrong.